# сложные условия оператора if

Tags: javascript, html

В javascript не работает условие:

```
if((y1 == 1 && y2 < 10 && y3 < 10) || (y1 == -1 && x < 2) || y1 == 0)
```

Не могу найти правила оформления сложных условий(

Comment: Здесь всё написано правильно. Почему Вы решили что условие не работает? Как оно должно работать? Синтаксис верный - и если условие не работает то Вы просто неправильно его продумали.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Синтаксических ошибок в нём нет? Нет. Значит, работает. Опишите какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: закрался "х" от Кирилла ) Во всех вариациях уже условия попробовал.

Comment: Почему ты решил, что условие не работает? На каких данных ты его проверял?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы путаетесь в своих условиях, то попробуйте дать им осмысленные имена. Вы удивитесь тому, как быстро придет понимание что и где не так ))

```
isClose = (y1 == 1 && y2 < 10 && y3 < 10);
isProtect = (y1 == -1 && x < 2) || y1 == 0;

if(isClose || isProtect) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: мне кажется, что вместо y1 == 1 && y2 < 10 везде нужно писать (y1 == 1) && (y2 < 10), что бы четко понимать порядок выполнения